# IPython not setting system status

Tags: python, ipython, popen

I'm using the subprocess module (Popen) to run a script using IPython, and it doesn't appear to be setting the system status correctly for the process.

```
#(script run_test.py)

import subprocess as proc

command = "ipython test.py"

p = proc.Popen( command, shell=True, cwd=None, stdout=proc.PIPE,
                stderr=proc.STDOUT )
( stdOut, stdErr ) = p.communicate()

print p.returncode

if p.returncode:
   raise Exception( stdOut )
```

In this example, "test.py" is just a simple script that raises (just `raise Exception()`). When I run this script from the command line (Redhat Enterprise 5.11) I get:

```
> python run_test.py
0
```

Now, if I change my command in "run_test.py" to use python (instead of IPython), I get:

```
(using command = "python test.py")
> python run_test.py
1
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "run_test.py", line 12, in <module>
    raise Exception( stdOut )
Exception: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 2, in <module>
    raise Exception()
Exception
```

Any tips on how to get ipython to set the system error code correctly?

Comment: Might be an IPython bug. Feel free to file [an issue](https://github.com/ipython/ipython/issues).

Comment: Just did, thanks for the link

Comment: You're welcome. I can reproduce the issue.